# С++ Есть способ получить базовый адрес процесса?

Tags: c++

Как в С++ получить базовый адрес процесса? Не могу найти примеров как получить такой адрес

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вероятно указать на эту программу, а вот как найти указатель это другой вопрос.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DWORD Module(LPSTR ModuleName) 
{
    HANDLE hModule = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPID);
    MODULEENTRY32 mEntry;
    mEntry.dwSize = sizeof(mEntry);
    do
        if (!strcmp(mEntry.szModule, ModuleName))
        {
            CloseHandle(hModule);
            return (DWORD)mEntry.modBaseAddr;
        }
    while (Module32Next(hModule, &mEntry));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что это и как это связано с заданным вопросом??? Почему ведется работа с неинициализированным `mEntry.szModule`? Где вызов `Module32First`?